# Github pages и localStorage

Tags: javascript, github, localstorage, github-pages

Собственно, вопрос. Если я размещу сайт на гитхаб пейджес, будет ли работать локальное хранилище, задаваемое через интерфейс `Window.localStorage`?

А если подсоединю к репозиторию своё доменное имя с субдоменом, типа  blog.example.com?

Comment: `localStorage` никак не связан с тем где размещен сайт

Comment: @Grundy понимаю, что вопрос супер-глупый :D Просто никогда не юзал, не хочу просчитаться. Просто подумал, что он может сбрасываться на таком хостинге как-то. Нет?

Comment: собственно, он потому и `local`, что расположен в браузере. сервер про него ничего не знает.

Comment: @Grundy ну оно и ясно, да. Прост подстраховался. Спасибо.